# Changing the default session timeout of a spring web application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, session-timeout

I have to test a web application that is written by spring and jsp. The default session-timeout for the application is 30 min.

I want to reduce the session-timeout. For doing this, I have changed in the `web.xml` file in `tomcatInstallationLocation/conf/`. But it doesn't work. The default configuration in `tomcatInstallationLocation/conf/web.xml` was -

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Where I've just changed the time and make it -

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

But is still doesn't work. As I know far, in this situation I have to make a change in my spring application's `web.xml`. But I'm not sure. Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Session timeout hierarchy:

- `$tomcat_home/conf/web.xml`
- `$your_webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`
- manual invocation of `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int)`

Each subsequent entry overrides others above.